# Stop duplication of data in left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects data from several tables using LEFT JOINS. The problem is data is being duplicated.

Here's the query

```
SELECT 
A.ID,
T.T_ID,
T.name,
T.pic,
T.timestamp AS T_ts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_plays WHERE T_ID = T.T_ID) AS plays,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_downloads WHERE T.T_ID) AS downloads,
S.S_ID,
S.status,
S.timestamp AS S_ts,
G.G_ID,                                                
G.gig_name,
G.date_time,
G.lineup,
G.price, 
G.currency,
G.pic AS G_pic,
G.ticket,
G.venue,
G.timestamp AS G_ts

FROM artists A
LEFT JOIN TRACKS T
ON T.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN STATUS S
ON S.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN GIGS G
ON G.ID = A.ID

WHERE A.ID = '$ID'
ORDER BY S_ts, G_ts AND T_ts DESC LIMIT 20
```

The problem is data is duplicated if one of the tables in the join has more data than another. So if tracks has 1 row, status has 2 and gigs has no rows you would get the data from tracks doubled.

I have tried using `GROUP BY A.ID` but that eliminates data. So in the example given before there would nly be one row of `status` show.

I've also tried `GROUP_CONCAT` but am unsure on that function so can't tell you much.

USING `SELECT DISTINCT` has the same effect as just the `GROUP BY A.ID`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way SQL joins work. If you do not want to get duplicated data, run your queries separately, and do your joining in memory.

Comment: This is a conceptual problem rather than a technical one.  You need to decide which status (of possibly many) you want to retrieve for each track.  Same for gigs.

Comment: @nbs189 . . . If `tracks` has two rows, which one do you choose?  You've given SQL no way to differentiate one row from another so of course the query is going to bring you back both.  That is what it is asking for.

Comment: You write: "...if tracks has 1 row, status has 2 and gigs has no rows you would get the data from tracks doubled.". What is the output that you would want instead?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that artists -> gigs and artists -> tracks are 1-N mappings then you have two choices. (both of which were covered in the comments on your OP

1) Specify which of the N rows you want to get back to achieve a 1-1 map:

```
FROM artists A
LEFT JOIN TRACKS T ON T.ID = A.ID AND T.<SOMETHING> = SOMETHING
LEFT JOIN STATUS S ON S.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN GIGS G ON G.ID = A.ID AND G.<SOMETHING> = SOMETHNING
```

2) Do the joins as you wrote and get multiple entries for tracks and gigs and then pivot them in your calling application. Generally you'd put an ORDER BY clause in the query and check for the same artist key and pivot the list.