# SQL - create a view of multiple tables joined together

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a view of multiple tables joined to a table called `artists` so that it can be easily referenced.

The arrangement of the data in the view is what i am struggling with. I need the joins to behave independently of each other so no data is duplicated. I'll give the query I have so far and then some examples;

```
CREATE VIEW stream_view AS
SELECT
A.ID,
T.T_ID,
T.name AS name,
T.pic AS T_pic,
T.timestamp AS T_ts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_plays WHERE T_ID = T.T_ID) AS plays,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_downloads WHERE T.T_ID) AS downloads,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE E_ID = T.ID AND event = 'T') AS T_likes,
S.S_ID,
S.status,
S.timestamp AS S_ts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE E_ID = S.ID AND event = 'S') AS S_likes,
G.G_ID,                                                
G.gig_name,
G.date_time,
G.lineup,
G.price, 
G.currency,
G.pic AS G_pic,
G.ticket,
G.venue,
G.timestamp AS G_ts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE E_ID = G.ID AND event = 'G') AS G_likes

FROM artists A
LEFT JOIN status S 
ON S.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN gigs G ON G.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN tracks T ON T.ID = A.ID
```

I will make some examples but only include the ID's of everything for simplicity.

**Example of what should happen**

Say I have two 3 `A.ID`'s of 1, 2 and 3. Each of these ID's has a few `G_ID`'s, `T_ID`'s and `S_ID`'s belonging to them. The view should come out so there are no duplicates and each `G_ID`, `T_ID` or `S_ID` is on a different row and is assigned to their `A_ID`. Something like this;

```
 A_ID    G_ID    T_ID    S_ID

 1       1       NULL    NULL
 1       NULL    4       NULL
 2       NULL    NULL    5
 3       2       NULL    NULL
 3       NULL    8       NULL
 3       NULL    NULL    8
```

**Example of what happens at the moment**

```
 A_ID    G_ID    T_ID    S_ID

 1       1       NULL    NULL
 1       1       4       NULL
 2       NULL    NULL    5
 3       2       NULL    NULL
 3       2       8       NULL
 3       2       8       8
```

As you can see the data is duplicated so that the table contains more than one of the same `G_ID`, `T_ID` or `S_ID`. These ID's are unique in their own column so their can't be duplicates of a `G_ID` but a `G_ID` and a `T_ID`, for example, can have the same values.

Comment: @marc_s Sorry, forgot to add that.

Comment: JFYI: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Stop duplication of data in left join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990630/stop-duplication-of-data-in-left-join) - at least one of the answers offered should return the output requested.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are joining the rows together.  It appears that you want a `union all` query instead.

This is the structure, based on the sample data you provided:

```
select a.*, t.*
from ((select a_id, g_id, null as t_id, null as s_id
       from gigs g
      ) union all
      (select a_id, null as g_id, t_id, null as s_id
       from tracks t
      ) union all
      (select a_id, null as g_id, null as t_id, s_id
       from status s
      )
     ) t join
     artists a
     on t.a_id = a.a_id
```

Comment: A union would work if the number of columns in each table were the same but as you can see from my query at the moment they are not.